# Why is onbeforeunload always showing a dialog

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to have my javascript pop a dialog if there is data that hasn't been written yet, but it is always showing the confirmation dialog, even if there is nothing to be written.

I have reduced the problem to this minimal failing case:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (e) => {
    e.returnValue = null;
    return null;
});
```

With this in my code, the windows always ask for confirmation (both Chrome and Firefox).  Changing the null's to undefined's doesn't change anything.

Can someone please lend me a clue?

Comment: _"With this in my code, the windows always ask for confirmation"_ - what else do you expect it to do? https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-beforeunload: _"Fired at the Window when the page is about to be unloaded, in case the page would like to show a warning prompt"_ - Are you under the impression that you could "trap" the user on a page by preventing them from leaving it for a different location without them having any say in the matter ...? Of course not.

Comment: I think he's just giving them a chance to let their data finishing sending. Sounds like a warning to me, not a trap. I imagine a similar scenario to Google Docs in offline mode after making some edits.

Comment: No, of course not.  The goal is to have the user's request to navigate away executed without bothering him with a dialog.  Deadpixels' response below was exactly the answer I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A confirmation dialog will be displayed if `event.returnValue` is set to a non-empty. `undefined` and `null` aren't empty in Javascript.
You should use a conditional and only set/return something if the conditional is true. In other words:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (e) => {
    if (dataWaitingToBeSent) {
        e.returnValue = null;
        return null;
    }
});
```

References:
[beforeUnload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload), [null primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null), [empty statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/Empty)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `return;` in order to avoid triggering the confirmation prompt.

In case if you return '',null,false it may trigger the prompt.

If you want to disable the dialog

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (e) => {
    .....
return;
});
```

Hope this helps ...!

Working fiddle on jquery: https://jsfiddle.net/KishorVelayutham/wfd2xsxk/10/

```
return ; will stop prompting the dialog.
```

Comment: I tried setting returnValue to undefined and returning undefined, and it still showed the confirmation dialog.  Also with false, "false", and "".

Comment: Check it out @Jabberwock

Comment: But isn't `return;` and `return undefined;` identical? `(function f() { return; })() === (function g() { return undefined; })() // true`